# composition of Inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

There is probably already a question about this but I couldn't find it.

I'm sure there is a simple solution but I can't see it.

Let's say you have the following:

```
class FooBase
{
protected:
    BarBase myInstance;
}

class FooChild : public FooBase
{
protected:
    BarChild myInstance;
}

class BarChild : public BarBase
{
}
```

So basically, you want to use the derived version of BarBase in the FooChild class.

I think that in the above code,  there will be 2 different instances of myInstance (one BarBase and one BarChild).

I would like to have only one instance so that I can use BarBase in FooBase and I can use BarChild in FooChild.

Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this so that only one instance is created.

```
#include <iostream>

class BarBase
{
}
;
class BarChild : public BarBase
{
}
;

class FooBase
{
public:
  FooBase(BarBase* baseBar);
protected:
  BarBase* myInstance;
}
;


class FooChild : public FooBase
{
public:
  FooChild(BarBase* base)
;
}
;


FooBase::FooBase(BarBase* baseBar)
{
  myInstance = baseBar;
}

FooChild::FooChild(BarBase* childBar) : FooBase(childBar)
{

}

int main()
{
  BarChild *bc = new BarChild();
  FooChild fc(bc);
}
```

I don't know either this is the right solution or it's elegant one ;)

Comment: But then the myInstance you get in FooChild is BarBase.

Answer (score 0):

Are templates an option?

```
tempalate <typename T = BarBase>
class FooBase{
protected:
    T myInstance;
};

class FooChild : public FooBase<BarChild> {};
```

If I use `int` and `double` to test this works as desired using only one member variable: http://ideone.com/nOfR5x

It does however require declarations of `FooBase` to be followed by angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualization is what you're looking for i believe. Give it a look. You can simply use a Constructor Method which creates those variables. If you create a derived class, then it calls that class's constructor, which creates that variable.

Comment: At least a link to **look** at may help, What do you suggest, Wikipedia has a [Dynamic polymorhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Dynamic_polymorphism) section in its C++ article.